# Python program, no output displayed when i run

Tags: python, fibonacci

python newbie here. I have a code below, but when i run the code nothing displays.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n <= 1:
      return n
    else:
      return fibonacci (n-1) + fibonacci (n-2)
```

what am I missing ? is it a print statement ? when i add print (), I get 327 as the result, but i don't think that is Fibonacci series.

Comment: Because you don't use command print()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print out the first 10 fibonacci numbers according to your code. Without a print statement, you will see no output.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n <= 1:
      return n
    else:
      return fibonacci (n-1) + fibonacci (n-2)

for i in range(10):
    print(fibonacci(i))
```

Your current fibonacci() function just *returns* the value, you can either take that return value and print it, as I did above, or not return anything and just print the value directly in the function (see below)

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n <= 1:
      print(n)
    else:
      print(fibonacci (n-1) + fibonacci (n-2))

for i in range(10):
    fibonacci(i)
```

Comment: Thanks, i understand your first code, when i run the second code, i don't see output even though there is a print statement ?

Comment: @Jag Thanks for pointing that out! I've just edited in the statement that calls the function. The problem was, fibonacci() is a function that actually needs to be called. I would suggest you do some research into how functions are meant to be used and what their purpose is, they are incredibly useful but can be a confusing concept. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp